# Unity3D RigidBody MovePosition Flicker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I currently am working on a game where I am using click to move in Unity. When I click on a spot on the map, I set that mouse's click to the destination and then use the rigidBody on the gameobject to move it using RigidBody.MovePosition(). When I do this, I am getting a lot of flicker when the gameobject reaches its destination. Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

```
    // COMPONENTS
Rigidbody rigidBody;

// MOVEMENT
Vector3 destination;
Vector3 direction;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    destination = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    DetectInput();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    MoveControlledPlayer();
}

void MoveControlledPlayer()
{

    transform.LookAt(destination);
    Vector3 direction = (destination - transform.position).normalized;
    rigidBody.MovePosition(transform.position + direction * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
}

void DetectInput()
{
   if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        SetDestination();
    }
}

void SetDestination()
{
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
    Plane field = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
    Ray ray;
    float point = 0;

    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (field.Raycast(ray, out point))
        destination = ray.GetPoint(point);

     }
}
```

Comment: Your destination is a point. So it is hard to reach the *exact* same position. You should add some code managing the case when your destination is really, really close from your object.

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me. Simple and easy fix. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reaching a point when using a velocity-based behavior is really hard, and often results in flickering: that's because the object is always passing over his destination.

A way to fix it is to stop the movement when the object is close enought to the target.

Answer (score 1):

I do these kind of movements with **temporary joints**. They are extremely accurate / configurable / embeddable.

In 2D I use a [`DistanceJoint2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DistanceJoint2D.html) to control distance between rigidbody points, or between a body and a world point. In 3D you could use [`SpringJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpringJoint.html) or [`ConfigurableJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ConfigurableJoint.html).

Then just tween the distance basically the same way you do per frame moving now (on `FixedUpdate`).